# C / binding multiple sockets [on differnet ports]

Tags: c, sockets

I want to bind 4 sockets on different ports. Somehow I get always the `: Address already in use` error. For the first loop, the `case PORT1` it is working, but when coming to the second run I get the above mentioned error. It would be nice, if someone could take a closer look at my code.

The output looks like that:

```
thread 0 started, pc_packet_receiver 
sock_fd[8]
sock_fd[8], fdmax[8]
sock_fd[9]
error: could not bind UDP socket, port2
: Address already in use
```

As you can see, the first `printf` in the loop is processed twice and when `bind` is called for `PORT2` the program crashes.

- `sock_fd` is an array of file descriptors
- `sock_addr_port[1..4]` are four different `struct sock_addr`
- the values `PORT1/PORT2/PORT3/PORT4` are defined in an `enum [1..4]`
- in the end I want to add all `sock_fd[i]` into a `FD_SET` to processing them with `select`

thank you very much in advance for your help.

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    if((sock_fd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("error: could not open UDP socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\tsock_fd[%d]\n", sock_fd[i]);

    switch (i+1) {
        case PORT1:
            bzero(&sock_addr_port1, sock_len_port1);
            sock_addr_port1.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sock_addr_port1.sin_port = htons(ETH_PORT1);
            sock_addr_port1.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

            if(bind(sock_fd[i], (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr_port1, sock_len_port1) < 0) {
                perror("error: could not bind UDP socket, port1\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            break;
        case PORT2:
            bzero(&sock_addr_port2, sock_len_port2);
            sock_addr_port2.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sock_addr_port2.sin_port = htons(ETH_PORT2);
            sock_addr_port2.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

            if(bind(sock_fd[i], (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr_port2, sock_len_port2) < 0) {
                perror("error: could not bind UDP socket, port2\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            break;
        case PORT3:
            bzero(&sock_addr_port3, sock_len_port3);
            sock_addr_port3.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sock_addr_port3.sin_port = htons(ETH_PORT3);
            sock_addr_port3.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

            if(bind(sock_fd[i], (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr_port3, sock_len_port3) < 0) {
                perror("error: could not bind UDP socket, port3\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            break;
        case PORT4:
            bzero(&sock_addr_port4, sock_len_port4);
            sock_addr_port4.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sock_addr_port4.sin_port = htons(ETH_PORT4);
            sock_addr_port4.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

            if(bind(sock_fd[i], (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr_port4, sock_len_port4) < 0) {
                perror("error: could not bind UDP socket, port4\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    FD_SET(sock_fd[i], &read_fds);
    fdmax = sock_fd[i];
    printf("sock_fd[%d], fdmax[%d]\n", sock_fd[i], fdmax);
}
```

Comment: What are `ETH_PORT1`, `ETH_PORT2`, etc ?

Comment: Unless you defined `ETH_PORT2` to be the same as `ETH_PORT1` it shouldn't be a problem. A small note though: There is lot of duplicated code, in the `switch` statement just set the port to bind to, and do the actual `bind` (together with all other setup) after the `switch` statement.

Comment: guys, thanks so much, I made a "stupid" mistake when copying some lines, of course you are right, `ETH_PORT1` and `ETH_PORT2` were defined with same value :( man!!! now it is working. should I delete that question?!

Answer (score 0):

There is another process running which uses `ETH_PORT2` right now. You should be able to see this when you run `netstat -tan` (`-tn` on Windows) on the command line.

Google for "which process uses which port" to see how you can find out the process.